# Definite integration involving Trigonometry.

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

$$ \frac{\int_0^{\pi/2} (\sin x)^{2½+1} \, dx}{\int_0^{\pi/2} (\sin x)^{2½-1} \, dx}$$
I'm puzzled. 
How to proceed...

[image]

Comment: A: I have no idea what you're asking, B: It looks like you've done absolutely no work of your own, which is going to get your question locked in a hurry.

Comment: Yes I have tried it. As many times I could. I find difficulty in typing the whole process using scripts & subscripts here. That's why I posted only to the point question.

Comment: Your formula makes no sense as written.  Is this supposed to be 
$$ \int_0^{\pi/2} \dfrac{\sin(x)^{5/2} + 1}{\sin(x)^{5/2}-1}\; dx$$
or $$ \dfrac{\int_0^{\pi/2} \sin(x)^{7/2} \; dx}{\int_0^{\pi/2} \sin(x)^{3/2}\; dx}$$?

Comment: @RobertIsrael The OP has been edited, it is the latter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have
$$\sin^{\sqrt{2}+1}x=\sin^{\sqrt{2}-1}x\sin^2x=\sin^{\sqrt{2}-1}x-\sin^{\sqrt{2}-1}x\cos^2x.$$
Now use integration by parts
$$\int f'g=fg-\int fg'$$
with 
$$f(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\sin^{\sqrt{2}}x,\quad g(x)=\cos x,$$
it follows that
$$\begin{aligned}&\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\sin^{\sqrt{2}-1}x\cos^2x\\
=&\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\sin^{\sqrt{2}}x\cos x|_{x=0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\sin^{\sqrt{2}}x\sin xdx\\
=&\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\sin^{\sqrt{2}+1}xdx
\end{aligned}$$
Therefore
$$\begin{aligned}\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\sin^{\sqrt{2}+1}xdx&=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\sin^{\sqrt{2}-1}xdx-\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\sin^{\sqrt{2}-1}x\cos^2xdx\\
&=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\sin^{\sqrt{2}-1}xdx-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\sin^{\sqrt{2}+1}xdx,
\end{aligned}$$
which implies
$$\frac{\sqrt{2}+1}{\sqrt{2}}\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\sin^{\sqrt{2}+1}xdx=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\sin^{\sqrt{2}-1}xdx.$$
Hence
$$\frac{\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\sin^{\sqrt{2}+1}xdx}{\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\sin^{\sqrt{2}-1}xdx}=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{2}+1}=\sqrt{2}(\sqrt{2}-1)=2-\sqrt{2}.$$

Comment: The relation you concluded between numerator and denominator was impressive.